# NSDateFormatter not creating data

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdateformatter

What is wrong in this method? Return value is empty.

```
-(NSString *)newFormatDateStringFromOldFormatStringForTableView:(NSString *)oldString
{
// Old String "2013-11-29 15:00:00"
// New Required Stirng 'Fri, 01 Dec 2013'

// Convert string to date object
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
//[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy"];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:oldString];  

// Convert date object to desired output format
//[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEEE, MMMM d, YYYY"];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy"];
NSString *newString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];  
[dateFormat release];   

return newString;
}
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: There are thousands of examples of how to use NSDateFormatter here.  Look at a few of them.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The following code worked:)

```
+ (NSString *)userVisibleDateTimeStringForRFC3339DateTimeString:(NSString *)rfc3339DateTimeString {
/*
 Returns a user-visible date time string that corresponds to the specified
 RFC 3339 date time string. Note that this does not handle all possible
 RFC 3339 date time strings, just one of the most common styles.
 */

NSDateFormatter *rfc3339DateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];

[rfc3339DateFormatter setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];
[rfc3339DateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss"];
[rfc3339DateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

// Convert the RFC 3339 date time string to an NSDate.
NSDate *date = [rfc3339DateFormatter dateFromString:rfc3339DateTimeString];

NSString *userVisibleDateTimeString;
if (date != nil) {
    // Convert the date object to a user-visible date string.
    NSDateFormatter *userVisibleDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    assert(userVisibleDateFormatter != nil);
    [userVisibleDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy"];
    userVisibleDateTimeString = [userVisibleDateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
}else{
    userVisibleDateTimeString=rfc3339DateTimeString;
}
return userVisibleDateTimeString;
```

}

Comment: So if it worked, why didn't you use it from the start?

Comment: @HotLicks, I was looking for details about format specifiers and just saw it so I tried :) .. Is there something wrong with this approach ??

Comment: Nothing wrong with it, offhand.  May be a bit of overkill for your use.

Comment: If this solution works then why did you originally state that the date string was in a different format?

Answer (score 2):

You have to tell the full format of the old string like this

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
```

Comment: the object "date" is not creating somehow, its nil..

Comment: @Zubair It should work.

Comment: It should , but don't know why its not

Comment: if it doesn't work, maybe oldString is not what you think it is. Try to output oldString using NSLog as the first thing in the function.